# Flutter DatabaseException(UNIQUE constraint failed)

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I`m trying to insert some data into sqflite table but there is an error while executing insert query

```
await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE $catrgoryTable($category_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE  , $colDeviceTypeId INTEGER, '
                '$room_id INTEGER)');
        print('category created!');
```

and here is the Error

```
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(UNIQUE constraint failed: category_Table.category_id (code 1555)) sql 'INSERT INTO category_Table (category_id, device_type_id, room_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' args [1, 1, 1]})
```

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table `category_Table` has a unique constraint field on it, the error shows that you tried to enter a value for `category_id` that it already exists, which violates primary key's uniqueness constraint for this field. Only one row can exist with a given ID value. So If you're trying to insert a row, be sure that your `category_id` have a unique value, or if you don't care about generating ids by yourself, you can add `AUTOINCREMENT` setting to your `category_id` column definition. This way it will be filled automatically and each row will have its own unique value.

Answer (score 4):

```
static Future<void> insert(String table, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  final db = await DBHelper.database();
  db.insert(table, data, conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}
```

here is my code is thought if I use conflict algorithm replace it would replace that unique value ?

Answer (score 4):

In the insert function of database. Add

```
conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace.
```

it worked for me